# NSPredicate is not handling single quote so not comparing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate, apostrophe

I am using `NSPredicate` for filtering, I have single quote in the name.

I tried to use

```
 NSString *keywordWithBackslashedApostrophes = [keyword stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
```

but then it is not comparing as I saw it is comparing `Audit's` with `Audit\`'s so it not able to compare. 
I took strTemp from `NSDictionary`
but `NSDictionary` converts it into utf-8 code
I tried to use  `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MeetingRoomType = %@",strTemp]`

So I am not able to compare string with single quote as if I take from nsdictionary then it automatically converts to utf-8 code and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]` its not comparing.

Please help is there any option to use nspredicate with single quote or I need to use for loop only, as then I will need to change at all places

Following is the code for dictionary

```
NSDictionary *dicTemp = [arrTemp lastObject];
[dicTemp setValue:@"Audit's" forKey:@"Meeting"];
[arrTemp addObject:dicTemp];
```

and in predicate I use `[[arrTemp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Meeting"];`

Its not comparing

I use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Meeting = %@",[[arrTemp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Meeting"]]`

When I debug I get the utf-8 code instead of apostrophe and it does not come in comparision

Comment: If it's from an `NSDictionary` then it's probably an `NSString`, which has no guaranteed storage type. There's no automatic conversion to UTF-8 anywhere — if a byte stream is being interpreted as UTF-8 then you're asking for it explicitly somewhere. Can you post the code that makes the query and then applies it?

Comment: Question is added for required code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with something other than `NSPredicate`. The following code:

```
NSArray *array =
    @[
        @{
            @"Meeting" : @"Audit's"
        },
        @{
            @"Meeting" : @"Non-audit"
        }
    ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Meeting = %@", array[0][@"Meeting"]];

NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
NSLog(@"predicate: %@", predicate);
NSLog(@"filtered array: %@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Outputs:

```
2013-12-24 13:23:00.913 Untitled[2638:507] array: (
        {
        Meeting = "Audit's";
    },
        {
        Meeting = "Non-audit";
    }
)
2013-12-24 13:23:00.914 Untitled[2638:507] predicate: Meeting == "Audit's"
2013-12-24 13:23:00.915 Untitled[2638:507] filtered array: (
        {
        Meeting = "Audit's";
    }
)
```